# Is there an alternative for computing data using a nested for-loop in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of lists that contain county level info about a group's population. Each group has its own row.

```py
[['Autauga County, Alabama',
  'American Indian or Alaska Native Alone',
  '05000US01001',
  '3',
  '170',
  '61',
  '85',
  '45',
  '170',
  '61',
  '85',
  '45'],
 ['Autauga County, Alabama',
  'Asian Alone',
  '05000US01001',
  '4',
  '515',
  '162',
  '415',
  '98',
  '315',
  '154',
  '220',
  '120'],
 ['Autauga County, Alabama',
  'Black or African American Alone',
  '05000US01001',
  '5',
  '10420',
  '162',
  '7620',
  '71',
  '10420',
  '162',
  '7620',
  '71'],
 ['Autauga County, Alabama',
  'Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander Alone',
  '05000US01001',
  '6',
  '10',
  '20',
  '10',
  '20',
  '10',
  '20',
  '10',
  '20'],
 ['Autauga County, Alabama',
  'White Alone',
  '05000US01001',
  '7',
  '41550',
  '27',
  '31920',
  '27',
  '41400',
  '137',
  '31800',
  '90']]
```

Or another way to visualize the data:

County      | LNTITLE |  Population |

Los Angeles | White   |  6423432    |

Los Angeles | Black   |  4323333    |

Los Angeles | Hispanic|  32432444   |

Alameda     | White   |  24343243   |

Alameda     | Black   |  43234323243|

I'm trying to compute a racial fractionalization score for more granular levels, and the code I wrote works fine but it's rather slow for less than 3200 observations. The other data set where I want to compute racial fractionalization scores has well over 100000 observations and I worry my computer wont be able to handle such a load.

Question: What would you recommend that I do to make my code more efficient in handling larger datasets?

Cleaning and prep work:
I first decided to accumulate a list of unique county names. I then proceeded to write the Racial Fractionalization Score function.

I created an array to store counties that were not rows of Puerto Rico (a territory) and I wanted to ignore rows that contained Totals or Not Hispanic or Latino since these aren't racial groups and would make the estimate very erroneous.

Actual Approach (Last code chunk): 
I created an array called RFS_Store where my goal was to store the county name and RFS. I approached this by looping through each unique county, where I created another array to store the 4th indexed elements of rows that matched the county name. After the array was full, I would then proceed to store the returned RFS value of the inputted array and its corresponding county name.

```py
unique = []
for row in county:
    name = row[0]
    if name not in unique and "Puerto Rico" not in name:
        unique.append(name)

def RFS(county_values):
    total = sum(county_values)
    squares = []
    for item in county_values:
        squares.append((int(item)/total)**2)
    squared = sum(squares)
    return 1 - squared

new_county = []
for row in county:
    name = row[0]
    lntitle = row[1]
    if "Puerto Rico" not in name and lntitle != 'Total' and lntitle != "Not Hispanic or Latino":
        new_county.append(row)

RFS_Store = []
for elem in unique:
    stored = []
    for row in new_county:
        if elem == row[0]:
            stored.append(int(row[4]))
    RFS_Store.append([RFS(stored),elem])
```

There were no errors, except this process was kind of slow and the more I ran it, the more I noticed my computer acting weird.

Comment: You can either use pandas or numpy for vectorized computation. That will speed up your wofk

Comment: Was about to say that, for data crunching in python, pandas is awesome!